# AKS how to create pod configuration settings and secrets efficiently

Tags: azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-appservice

I have 10 Azure web apps that we are looking to migrate to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) from Azure App Service.  All apps are written in net core 3.1 or 5.0.  We are currently using Azure DevOps pipelines to deploy the applications to Azure App Service.  During the deployment, we use the FileTransform@2 task to transform the appsettings.json file for each app.  Some of the apps have 50-100 different configuration settings that are defined in the yaml file to correctly configure the running application. For example in our web app Azure DevOps pipelines statements like this can be found:

```
  - task: FileTransform@2
    displayName: Replace tokens in web zip file
    inputs:
      folderPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(webZipFile)'
      fileType: json
      xmlTransformationRules: ''
      enableXmlTransform: false
      jsonTargetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

where the webZipFile varible is the name of the application built zip file.  The good thing about using this method of deployment is that a yaml file can easily be reused across multiple applications which the only changes being the variables or parameters being passed into the file.

All we have to do then is define the variables that we want transformed in the yaml and the transformation works fine and as expected.

We have a single app in AKS already deployed.  In order to set the configuration in the app we have to perform the following steps (we are also using devops):

- create the variable in yaml
- transform the variable to base64
- create an appsettings.yml file for AKS and define all the secrets. something like this:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: webappsettings
  namespace: webapp  
type: Opaque
data:
  settingsconnections: __settingsconnectionsbase64__
```

- Define the deployment settings with the secret values

```html
n: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: webapp
  name: webapp
  namespace: webapp
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: organisation.azurecr.io/webapp:#{tagBuildId}#
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: webapp
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "100Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        env:
        - name: Settings__Connections
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webappsettings
              key: settingsconnections
```

- Add code to the webapp so that by default it reads environment settings rather than the appsettings.json file on startup.  This is so that we can use the same image across multiple environments. Of course the built image contains an appsettings file that has local development settings in it, so it's not appropriate to use that values when starting up.

The above process is very labour intensive and complex especially when we consider that we need to migrate multiple applications each with many application settings that need to be configured.

The question is, is there a more efficient way to set config and secrets at deploy time with Azure DevOps (or tasks on the marketplace)?  Ideally it would be something that would enable use to add all the config into the Azure DevOps pipeline yaml file on time, and some smart task would just somehow configure the container as it starts up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options, and it's arguable whether one approach is better or more correct than another.

One approach is to use Azure App Configuration and Azure KeyVault (or equivalent services) and let your applications retrieve configuration values at runtime. Instead of managing hundreds of app settings in config files or environment variables, your config files just point to the services, and your application can automatically retrieve the correct values at runtime.

You can also create [configmaps containing file data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-specific-path-in-the-volume), then mount the configmap as a volume, so a "file" exists on disk within the pod.

At the end of the day, you're going to have to do *some* amount of work and standardize on an approach. One thing I will say is that you should *not* use Azure Pipeline variables to drive application configuration -- application configuration should be **decoupled** from your continuous delivery provider. You should be able to deploy a working copy of your application *without* running a pipeline. This makes swapping pipeline providers easier in the future, as well as enabling rapid development, testing, and debugging of the application locally.

Comment: thanks Daniel. I prefer the second option because we've had problems added lots of different values to keyvaults as there seems to be an issue with Terraform and Keyvaults when the get beyond a certain number of values.  Agreed that i will have to do some work of course.  However, i'm looking for a sustainable approach so that when we migrate multiple apps we have something that works consistently.  let me investigate further.  thanks